# How to avoid self reference with IsWorkBookOpen

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to use shared excel workbooks on server which would be variously connected to each other.

I worked on it for many days to only find out it has many problems to cope with as shared workbooks do not support many features.

- I wanted the macro to check on opening the file to find out whether the file is opened by someone else and if "yes", it would tell the person to come back later.
- Unfortunately, I am now referencing to myself and this creates a loop.
- I open the file, it checks itself it is opened already and then after the message it closes.

Could you please help me to  evade the loop so it would suit the purpose?

I believe only the upper part of the code relates to my problem, so I do not post it in full:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim Ret

    Ret = IsWorkBookOpen(ThisWorkbook.FullName)

    If Ret = True Then
        MsgBox "Come back later."
    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use that function for your purpose.
You can actually check the status of the file using:

```
ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly
```

which returns a boolean; true if file is readonly.

Now, before opening the file you really cannot suppress the pop up asking if you want to open it as read only or not. But you can still try putting this code which will trigger once the user opened the file as read only.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
        MsgBox "Comeback some other time. File in use"
        ThisWorkbook.Close False
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I have just tested both yours and brett's readonly approach and it does not work with shared workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of the `IsWorkBookOpen` approach is the speed compared to opening the workbook over a network compared to a `ReadOnly` test.

I would recommend you change your approach to load the check from a `vbs`, or a separate Excel file - as this is the best method.

1. The code below can be save in NotePad on your network drive as a `vbs`, say *check.vbs*. The code checks if the file is open, if not then it launches the file in a new instance of Excel. If it is, a message is provided.

*vbs code*

```
Dim objExcel
FileName = "C:\temp\file.xlsm"
If Not IsWorkBookOpen(FileName) Then
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set ojbWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
    objExcel.Visible = True
Else
    wscript.echo FileName & " already opened"
End If

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName)
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
On Error Resume Next
Set objFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filename, 8, False)
ErrNo = Err   
ObjFile.Close
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
set objFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

2. If you want to run the check from the actual file then you will need to change to the `ReadOnly` test

   *code*

`Private Sub Workbook_Open()`
`If Me.ReadOnly Then MsgBox "file already opened", vbCritical`
`End Sub`

Comment: Totally agree on changing the approach :)

Comment: 1/ The readonly approach cannot work I believe. As I said, I want to use so called shared workbook. I think these shared workbooks do not prompt you for readonly, instead they let you collaborate. If I would know what "state" is the application in while opened in shared mode, maybe I could use the same approach for checking whether there is some temporary file opened...?

Comment: 2/ I tried to explain that in the end there will be many versions of the file I am creating. This is like a template and a user will take it, rename it on server and work in it (in shared mode). I do not want to enter into it every time and insert a full path (It is not even possible as in shared workbook you cannot edit VBA). This is why I tried to create a general VBA that would itself link to the file. The proposal with VBS would mean that I would need to create anew VBS every time there is a new file, right?

Answer (score 0):

I post this as I have seen this question unanswered on other forums, too.

I wanted to use many shared excel workbooks on server which would be variously connected to each other.

I wanted to use the so called shared workbook so everyone could access it and especially for the reason that it would track the changes within (users, time,...)

I wanted the macro to check on opening the file to find out whether the file is opened by someone else and if "yes", it would tell the person to come back later.

Suggested replies here could not help and I believe there is no chance to create a macro for path of the file itself so that IsWorkBookOpen(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
 could be used the way I tried.

I decided to write macro that would track changes within the Workbook as if it was "shared". This way I was able to "unshare" it and use the ReadOnly approach discussed here.